# iPv6 support for Application (objective-c)

Tags: ios, ipv6

Apple has mentioned in their document to eliminate some API for iPV6 support.
We are using below API in our application.

```
inet_ntoa()   
inet_aton()
```

Is there any other API instead of above API for support both IPv4 & IPv6?

Answer (score 0):

inet_ntoa(3N) interprets an IPv4 internet address and converts it to a character string.
instead of inetntoa function i used inet_ntop(3N) function.
This function perform the same operation for both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses

**below link helped me lot to support iPv6 for my app.**
http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/SDK_netapi/sockC.PortIPv4appIPv6.html

Comment: Unfortunately the above link is broken!
It's better if you could have provided some guided Code Snippets so everybody can go through it and get their issues resolved.

Comment: Alternate link: http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/SDK_netapi/sockC.PortIPv4appIPv6.html